# object inside object first one feemap is static one inside that uuid will be given by dynamically and it is a object that one will act like value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

```
"feeMap": {
      "6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793": {
        "id": "6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793",
        "name": "visnhuuuu666",
        "description": "One Time fee",
        "cost": 13,
        "isOneTimeFee": true,
        "isProrated": false,
        "prorateToDay": false,
        "discountable": true,
        "prepayable": true
      }
    }
    inside feemap that id is a uuid how can do like that. this "6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793": uuid is acts like object and that uuid only act as inner id value also how can I do like that dynamically is it possible. please help me this problem
```

I want feemap inside object should be given dynamically that is uuid and that one acts like object and also inside that object for id value also that same object uuid will add here

Answer (score 0):

you can use strings for field name sin JS and access them too like so:

```
let feeMap = {};
feeMap["6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793"] = {};
feeMap["6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793"].id = "6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793";
feeMap["6874597a-3b20-40ea-bfa3-08358ad19793"].name = "visnhuuuu666";
//and so on....
```

Please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#accessing_properties